# How to store html tags in wordpress

Tags: html, database, wordpress

How can i make my wordpress database store data with html tags :

`(eg. <p>, <tr>, </br>, etc)`

instead of plain text.

Comment: That's not a good idea.

Comment: I have to agree with @slime. The principle of a CMS is to separate the content from the display. You wouldn't want that kind of data stored with the content as it is only relevant to the view of the page. Can you post what code you are working on?

Answer (score -1):

Change the format! On the default editor then you can able to see:
[image: post editor with an arrow pointing to the Visual tab]

Comment: As this is a portal about programming I doubt the question was about usage.